# MySql Near Search

Tags: sql, search

Example, I want to search for "John Smith" in "My name is John Joe Smith and I live in America". But with a limit of 5 characters between "John" and "Smith".

How could I get this with MySql (php)?

I am building a search engine for my database, I am already using MATCH AGAINST, but I also want to offer a different kind of search.

thank you, Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But with a limit of 5 characters between "John" and "Smith"

MySQL full text functions don't offer such flexibility as far as I know.  You can use `like` or regular expressions:

```
where col regexp 'John.{0,5}Smith'
```

If you do the full text search in a subquery, then this might actually have reasonable performance.

The delightful `like` expression is:

```
where col like '%John%Smith%' and
      col not like '%John______Smith%'
```

There are six `_`s.

Comment: «where col regexp 'John.{0,5}Smith'» is working great! With «LIKE», it doesn't seem to be as accurate as using regexp.

I guess if I want to search in more than one column I would use:
where colA regexp 'John.{0,5}Smith' AND/OR colB regexp 'John.{0,5}Smith'

Thanks,

Comment: @Andy62 . . . Yes, you would extend that to each column.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot get a ORDER BY to work...
SELECT 
count(ColA) AS totalColA,count(ColB) AS totalColB,ColA,ColB,ColC 
FROM 
myTable 
GROUP BY 
ColA,ColB 
HAVING 
ColA LIKE "%Smith%" OR ColB LIKE "%Smith%"...
This seems to work fine. But I don't know if it's better that way or using FROM WHERE instead of HAVING....I would like to ORDER BY DESC with the total number of counts but it doesn't work, it gives an empty result.ORDER BY SUM(totalColA + totalColB) DESC...   I tried the SUM in the SELECT same problem. Would you know if it's possible to obtain this type of ORDER BY?

Thanks,

Comment: @Andy62 . . . I think you should ask a new question.  This question is not about ordering.

Comment: I made an error with LIKE syntax at first. Definitely, LIKE is warp speed compared to REGEXP :o)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to explore

> `SOUNDEX()`

, this will help you to achieve what you need, e.g. auto suggest functionality.
strings. but it comes with few drawbacks as   only the first few characters are taken into account, first letter must be the same or you won't find a match easily.

For more advanced needs, I think you need to look at the

> Levenshtein distance aka "edit distance" of two strings and work with
> a threshold

. This is the more complex yet slower solution, but it comes with better flexibility

You might want refer example tutorial here

[https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/#:~:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,not%20match%20exactly%20the%20fields](https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,not%20match%20exactly%20the%20fields).

Comment: I tried SOUNDEX () and like you said there are downsides. I didn't know about Levenshtein distance, it's a complex function, too much for me. Interesting and I found other types of search while looking for Levenshtein.

Thanks,
Andy